# Format the date & time based on the chosen date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, format

I've an input field(HTML5) to choose a date.
How do I get, the date & time both from that field to be saved in the variable 'myDate' in the format - Apr 18, 2017 3:25:00 PM ?

```html
Choose a date:
<input type="date" id="myDate" placeholder="Choose your date">
```

Here's my code -

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done?
(To everyone else: please can we not answer this question until the OP has added more effort)

Answer (score 0):

use the input type as **datetime-local** using the below way 
after getting the value of dateTime you can format in any format using javascript

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="dateTimePicker"/>
 <input type="button" onclick="myFun()"/>
 <script>
  function myFun() {
  var dateTime=document.getElementById("dateTimePicker").value;
  alert(new Date(dateTime));
  //or simply alert(dateTime)
  }
 <script>
```